# Assigning child classes to a variable in parent class

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I have these related classes:

```
class cars {

    public $cars;

    public function addCar($name, $car)
    {
        $this->cars[$name] = $car;
    }

    public function getCars()
    {
        return $this->cars;
    }

    public function getCar($name)
    {
        return $this->cars[$name];
    }

    public function getParams()
    {
        return $this->params;
    }
}

$cars = new cars();

class bmw extends cars {

    private static $_instance = null;
    protected $params;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->params['param'] = 'foo';
    }

    public static function init()
    {
        if (self::$_instance === null) {
            self::$_instance = new self;
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }
}

$cars->addCar( 'bmw', bmw::init() );
```

Basically i need to access all child classes from parent class. And use methods defined in parent class on those defined child classes. Parent class should not be modified when adding new child classes.

In the end this should work like this:

```
foreach( $cars->getCars() as $car )
{
    foreach( $car->getParams() as $key => $param )
        echo "$key = $param";
}
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: `Basically i need to access all child classes from parent class` so you want to reinvent OOP?  that is something very unexpectable :-)

Comment: There's something really weird going on. "Cars" is an array, but "bmw", which extends it, is a single instance (of sorts). It is not really clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I want to get all child instances of class cars in a var and then use methods defined in cars class on those instances.

Comment: Can't you collect the instances in question in another container/registry? Why does it have to be automagically ...on the class level? At the very least it will be harder to get rid of unused instances, the gc alone can't help you anymore when you have an automagic-running-object-table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really difficult to provide an help since it's not so clear what you're trying to achieve.

It seems to me that you need Registry Class (carDealer), an abstract class with common (for each child) methods and a child (Bmw) of this.

So, something like:

```
// You seems to need what is called sometimes a Registry. 
// Something which deal with keeping and delivering a group of 'related' classes, as a register.
class CarsDealer
{
    public $cars;

    public function addCar($name, $car)
    {
        $this->cars[$name] = $car;
    }

    public function getCars()
    {
        return $this->cars;
    }

    public function getCar($name)
    {
        return $this->cars[$name];
    }
}

// then you need a basic contract for each concrete classes 
// that will have the same nature and so will extend it 
abstract class Car
{
    protected $params;

    public function getParams()
    {
        return $this->params;
    }
}

// finally the concrete class
class Bmw extends Car
{
    public function __construct($params = null)
    {
        $this->params['param'] = $params;
    }
}

$carsDealer = new CarsDealer();

$carsDealer->addCar('bmw', new Bmw('foo'));

foreach ($carsDealer->getCars() as $car)
{
    foreach ($car->getParams() as $key => $param) {
        echo "$key = $param";
    }
}
```

Please pay attention to some basic rules/good practices/conventions:

- class naming, always capitalized
- Responsibilities (a class Bmw shouldn't have a method getCars, at least not in this example)
- [Visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php) of method, parameters
- http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/
- http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

Comment: I should probably use Registry for this. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Just one another approach, if you just need get this 'params' :-)

```
class cars {

    public $cars;

    public function addCar($name, $car)
    {
        $this->cars[$name] = $car;
    }

    public function getCars()
    {
        return $this->cars;
    }

    public function getCar($name)
    {
        return $this->cars[$name];
    }

    public function getParams($obj)
    {
        return $obj->params;
    }


}

$cars = new cars();

class bmw extends cars {

    private static $_instance = null;
    protected $params;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->params['param'] = 'foo';
    }

    public static function init()
    {
        if (self::$_instance === null) {
            self::$_instance = new self;
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }
}

$cars->addCar( 'bmw', bmw::init() );

print_r( $cars->getParams($cars->getCar('bmw')));
```